# Serializer `validate()` not getting called on `is_valid()` on POST

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to create a non class-based form to facilitate uniform logging in by users across all front-end apps. Currently, it looks like this

My serializer class:

```
class EmployeeLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)

    def validate_credentials(self, attrs):
        print('validating')
        try:
            emp: Employee = Employee.objects.get(username=attrs['username'])
            if crypto.verify_password(attrs['password'], emp.password_hash):
                return attrs
        except Exception:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect username or password")
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect username or password')
```

My view class:

```
class TestView(APIView):
serializer_class = EmployeeLoginSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response({'Message': 'Get works'})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.POST)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.POST)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({'Message': 'Credentials were correct'})
```

My issue is that `serializer.is_valid()` doesn't seem to be calling on validate automatically. I know I could just call `serializer.validate()` manually but all the docs and questions on StackOverflow seem to show `validate()` being called by `is_valid()` automatically so I get that feeling that that wouldn't be the best practice. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`is_valid()`** method will call **`validate()`** method of the serializer and `validate_FIELD_NAME()` methods. 
In your code, the **`validate_credentials()`** seems a ***regular class method*** which won't detect by DRF since the **`credentials`** isn't a **`field`** on the serializer.